# Internet Explorer CORS Issue - Google IMA HTML5 SDK

Tags: cors, internet-explorer-11, same-origin-policy, google-ima

I'm working on a project which involves showing Google IMA HTML5 SDK - driven video advertisements. Everything works with no exceptions except when it comes to Internet Explorer 11 (latest 'Edge' release working fine).

In IE11, the video advertisement is sometimes shown, but is unresponsive to input calls (Play, Pause, Volume etc). The console is showing that a number of URLs don't have the correct CORS/Cross-Origin Policy details in place. However, they do, as they work across the board in all other browsers.

Does IE11 need some additional help with CORS? Apologies, but I am unable to provide a demo or specific URLs as specified by the project owner.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the video ad is shown then I don't think CORS is the cause for the unresponsive input calls.  The reason is, if IE is blocking some resources from serving due to the improper header, then the ad would not show at all.

If the player controls are unresponsive, you will have to narrow down on some of the potential causes.  It could be the player itself, or the ad (VPAID ads can manipulate the DOM when initialized in the [`INSECURE` mode](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/vpaid2js#enabling)), or the IMA SDK.

To narrow down, test some of the test tags [over here](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/tags) in your implementation.  If you are **able** to reproduce the issue locally, then do a quick check of the video player you use.  To test using IMA's sample player, use our [Video Suite Inspector](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/vastinspector).  If you see the issue in the VSI, then it is a bug, for which you have to let us know at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ima-sdk.